# a*b* and (ab)* same or not?

Tags: regex, grammar, nfa

are a*b* and (ab)* the same language? I am trying to make nfa for a*b*

Comment: `a*b*` not the same as `(ab)*`. You can have the word `a` with the first, but cannot with the second.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong on cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two regular expressions define different languages.

`a*b*` matches any number of repetitions (including zero) of `a` followed by any number of repetitions (including zero) of `b`. For example `aaabb`.

`(ab)*` matches any number of repetitions (including zero) of the `ab` sequence, for example `abab`.

The empty string and `ab` are the only two words that match both regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

a * b * is not same as (ab)* for example : you can get in a * b * { a,b,aaab,aabbb...}
where as (ab)* {epsilon,ab,abab,ababab...}

Answer (score -1):

a*b* is the same of (a+b)* but not the (ab)*